# Break down output of wp_list_categories

Tags: categories

Im looking at how to breakdown the output from **wp_list_categories**. Currently it shows:

```
<a href="http://www.oddpandadesign.co.uk/shaun/cat-band/drummer/" title="View all posts filed under Drummer">Drummer</a>
```

But I am looking to only get the category name without the link. So would be `Drummer`.

My full code to get the category:

```
                    <?php //Set Variable URL for ALL catefory
                    $alllink = get_post_type_archive_link( 'opd-band' ); ?>

                    <?php //Category Display for Custom Post type - Video
                    $customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('opd-band');
                    if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0)
                    {
                        foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax)
                        {
                            $args = array(
                                'orderby' => 'name',
                                'show_count' => 0,
                                'pad_counts' => 0,
                                'hierarchical' => 1,
                                'taxonomy' => $tax,
                                'title_li' => '',
                                'data-filter' => '',
                                'echo' => 0,
                              );

                            echo 'Categories: <ul id="opd-filters" class="tags-button">';
                            echo  '<li><a href="#" data-filter="*">All</a>';
                            echo str_replace( '<br />', '', wp_list_categories( $args ) );
                            echo '</ul>';


                        }
                    } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom category walker should do what you need.

```
class My_Cat_Walker extends Walker_Category {
  function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    extract($args);

    $cat_name = esc_attr( $category->name );
    $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category );

    $output .= '<li>'.$cat_name.'</li>';
  }
}

$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'show_count' => 0,
  'hierarchical' => 1,
  'taxonomy' => $tax,
  'title_li' => '',
  'data-filter' => '',
  'hide_empty' => false,
  'walker' => new My_Cat_Walker
);
echo '<ul>';
  wp_list_categories($args);
echo '</ul>';
```

If you look at the [source for the parent walker](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L767), you will notice that the [`start_el()` method](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L840) does a lot more work that this one does. I don't know how complex you need this walker to be. What you see above is a very bare bones version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<?php
  $category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
  foreach($category_ids as $cat_id) {
  $cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id);
  echo $cat_name."<br/>";
 }
?>
```

For more details, check https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_all_category_ids

I hope you get an idea...